# What is Composer equivalent for npm install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I created a Laravel project with composer and published it on my github repo.
Usually, with a project with npm (like a React project), if I want to download the repository, then I have to run **npm i** or **npm install** to download all the dependencies listed in package.json.
Now, in a project made with composer, what's the equivalent command?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Composer has a good documentation about all built-in commands

Comment: better if the question is about "composer update" equivalent in npm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`composer install` is the command you are looking for. This will read your `composer.json` file and install all the necessary dependencies (into a `vendor` folder which is usually included in a `.gitignore` file.) This also generates a `composer.lock` file which is basically a file that contains the exact versions of the installed packages (unlike `composer.json` which contains a general version number.)